# IdentityServer4 Testserver could not found

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-testhost

I am writing a test to get a token from `identity server4` using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost

```
   var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddIdentityServer()
                                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())                           
                                ;

                    })
                    .Configure(app =>
                    {
                        app.UseIdentityServer();
                    });
                var server = new TestServer(hostBuilder);
                var client = server.CreateClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");

                var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
```

Then disco.Error comes up with the following error

> Error connecting to
>   http://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration: An error
>   occurred while sending the request.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The discovery client is obviously doing an external call to that actual address. You want it to call the test server that happens to "live" InMemory.

Take a look at these tests [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/1fb5e1588ffb25f31b8770c7fe201c4e785ca2ea/src/IdentityServer4/test/IdentityServer.IntegrationTests/Clients/DiscoveryClient.cs#L29) for IdentityServer4 that tests the discovery document.

To answer your question though you need to use one of the overloaded methods for the `DiscoveryClient` that takes in a handler that would make the correct "call" to your InMemory test server. Below is an example of how this could be done.

```
var server = new TestServer(hostBuilder);
var handler = server.CreateHandler();
var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:5000", handler);
var discoveryDocument = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();
```

Also I highly recommend going over the IdentityServer4 integration tests if youre going to be doing some of your own tests like this.

Comment: this works like a charm, Thanks. But the link is broken :(

Comment: sorry, fixed link :)

Comment: link is broken again :(

Comment: @LuisPalacios fixed the broken link to a perma link. Hope this helps

Comment: It did!, Thank you!