# How to implement integration testing for IdentityServer4?

Tags: testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

This is more of a general question not a specific one, but I hope it might help someone in the future with the similar problem.

I am implementing IdentityServer4 for my business case where I initially want to set up authentication and authorization for a public API access. For that I will be initially using only ClientCredentials flow. For manually testing the usage flow and correct configuration and setup, I have created a small test API and a Client console app as in the sample projects from the documentation. But I want to automate it as I have almost completed the IdentityServer4 setup and am going to start working on the actual API itself.

So basically I want to do some integration testing against my implementation of the IdentityServer. But I have minimal experience regarding this topic so maybe you would have some suggestions or tips on how to set it up.

Should I set it up on the API side, when at least some endpoints are already done? But if my IdentityServer and the API are in different solutions, then for example for running these tests locally, I would still have to start IdentityServer manually and then could run the tests on the API project which connect against it?

Or for me it would make more sense to have the tests, the test api and client in the IdentityServer project (much in the same way it is done in the source code solution). But when looking at the source code integration tests, I saw they had a separate Startup class for IdentityServer startup. Should I do this similarly or rather configure the tests to run against the Startup class of my own IdentityServer project? Then I would have to copy all the appSettings files etc.

I know it's quite a general question and topic, but any pointers will be appreciated on how to actually test the correct thing. I know I don't need to test a lot about the functionality itself as it's also done in the source code solution, but I would rather have the integration tests for testing my own configuration etc, so if any of the components fail to communicate to each other, I would know immediately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mostly agree with your thoughts.

I had asked a question [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879515/identityserver4-testserver-could-not-found) before I started my IdentitySerever project. That was answered by @Lutando, and four users upvoted this (though no one like :( the question). Anyway, we have added few acceptance and integration tests for our project. You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879515/identityserver4-testserver-could-not-found) to find out some details about how to write this kind of test

> Or for me it would make more sense to have the tests, the test api and
>   client in the IdentityServer project (much in the same way it is done
>   in the source code solution). But when looking at the source code
>   integration tests, I saw they had a separate Startup class for
>   IdentityServer startup. Should I do this similarly or rather configure
>   the tests to run against the Startup class of my own IdentityServer
>   project?

I can tell how we proceed on this in our company (Not everyone like the idea). As our identityserver will deal only with Hybrid Flow (to authorize only mvc app, win app and rest api), we created some example projects (each for one kind) and run them through the `TestsServer`. We have some virtual methods on Startup class of IdentityServer so that we can seed data and connect to memory databases. **Each test creates its own database in memory**

Anyway, these tests have done their jobs very gracefully. It tooks 7 moths to finish implementing the IdentityServer with Admin Interfaces, and many times pointed us to the wrong implementation. **These tests are usually worth the effort**

Finally, I want to point out few things I have found while developing IdS4

- Integration tests are taking long time, so not to duplicate same kind of tests.
- As you mentioned in your question, IdentityServer4 source have already tests their code properly, so no need to tests how the identityServer4 is working. Just test the succeesful connection part.
- It is hard to test the assert with access_token or identityToken
- Use [browser client](https://github.com/tibold/IdentityServer4.Contrib.AspNetIdentity/blob/master/test/IdentityServer4.Contrib.AspNetIdentity.Tests/Common/BrowserClient.cs) to work with redirection and cookies
- Finally, it is difficult and time consuming to write integration tests in this way. I believe that we should just add enough test for basic functionality of interactions between the projects

However, if you are familier with **Selenium**/**Coded UI** or similar tools, better to write integration tests using those. I believe, writing few acceptance tests (or Service level tests) just to confirm that new code does not break the workflow is better approach

Finally, I would like to add some of our acceptance tests, that we found save our times

1. Login from MVC client
2. Login from a client and call a api from mvc client
3. Consent Page appears or do not appear based on settings
4. Call API from a console app
5. Api Call fails because of insufficient scopes
6. User claims added successfully
   ...

and number of integration tests we have is 22

Feel free to correct me if anything I mention here is not a right approach.

Best of luck with your IdentityServer4 implementation

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer! I know the question was quite general and broad, but these general suggestions is what I wanted. I think I would benefit a lot by being able to contact you privately at some point. But regarding your answer, I also started with the DiscoveryClient testing based on the source project. I have the same 4 lines which are in the answer of the link you shared, but I was wondering which Startup file did you provide for the WebHostBuilder? I agree with most of your points but I wouldn't touch Selenium just yet. Also, did you develop your own Admin UI?

Comment: overriden test startup passed to WebHostBuilder. Yes, we developed a small AdminUI

Comment: So just like they have it in the source project? A new separate Startup class inside the IntegrationTests project? But i'm struggling to understand how does it test the integration with my actual implementation of the IdS4? Currently I created new classes for Clients and Resources inside the Test project. The only way it makes sense for me that I am testing the correct thing would be just to have the exact same Client and Resource objects as in my real implementation. Otherwise it would just be a separate implementation for testing only and wouldn't guarantee that my real implementation works.

Comment: Think about the database, or seed data for testing, or a testing middleware. You do not need to test the thing that is already tested many times.

Comment: Yes, of course, I don't want to copy the tests already done in the IdS4 source project. But I want to test my production application. I have configured ApiResources and Clients and I want to test that it's done correctly. I want to have a test API which is protected by IdS4 and a test client which tries to use that API. And that for example HTTPS is correctly configured for IdS4 in AWS. But based on the integration tests in IdS4 source, there's an overridden test startup + seed data for Clients and Resources inside the test project. So it's like a separate config, it's not the same.