# GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync can not find the authority url - IdentiyServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I was trying to replace obsolete IdentityServer methods and types and as I had been warned about, I tried to replace `DiscoveryClient()` and `TokenClient()` with appropiate methods like in the examples of the latest identity server [docs](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/discovery.html).  When I try to get related endpoints by `GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync` it returns null even though I could read those values with current code and also get those values on browser.

Besides, when I by-pass the step of discovery and supplying the direct token endpoint `RequestTokenAsync` returns null because of Not Found exception.

For the sake of clearity of the question I should say that I have not changed anything (its settings or endpoints) in my Identity server project (from which I try to get access token).

Followings are my previous and updated code to achieve what I've described. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Previous Code (Working):**

```
        var testServer = new TestServer(builder);
        var client = testServer.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        var discoClient = new DiscoveryClient(AuthorityUrl) {Policy = {RequireHttps = false}};
        var disco = discoClient.GetAsync().Result;
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, ClientId, ClientSecret);
        var tokenResponse = tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(Scope).Result;
        client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
```

**Updated Code (Not Working):**

```
        var testServer = new TestServer(builder);
        var client = testServer.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        //var discoClient = new DiscoveryClient(AuthorityUrl) {Policy = {RequireHttps = false}};
        var disco = client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest()
        { Address = AuthorityUrl, Policy = new DiscoveryPolicy() { RequireHttps = false, Authority = AuthorityUrl} }).Result;
        ;
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            throw new Exception(disco.Error);
        }
        //var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, ClientId, ClientSecret);
        var tokenClient = client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest()
        { Address = disco.TokenEndpoint, ClientId = ClientId, ClientSecret = ClientSecret, GrantType = GrantType}).Result;
        //var tokenResponse = tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(Scope).Result;
        client.SetBearerToken(tokenClient.AccessToken);
        return client;
```

**Edit:**

Updated my code as shown below and still getting the same error.

```
        var testServer = new TestServer(builder);
        var client = testServer.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        //var discoClient = new DiscoveryClient(AuthorityUrl) {Policy = {RequireHttps = false}};
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest()
            { Address = AuthorityUrl, Policy = new DiscoveryPolicy() { RequireHttps = false, Authority = AuthorityUrl } });
        ;
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            throw new Exception(disco.Error);
        }
        //var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, ClientId, ClientSecret);
        var tokenClient =await client.RequestTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest()
            { Address = disco.TokenEndpoint, ClientId = ClientId, ClientSecret = ClientSecret, GrantType = GrantType , Scope = Scope});

        client.SetBearerToken(tokenClient.AccessToken);

        return client;
```

**Error:**

> "Error connecting to `AuthorityUrl`/.well-known/openid-configuration: Not Found"

Comment: You should await async methods: `await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync();`

Comment: Yes thats on the document but not the case. I get the result with .Result().

Comment: @RuardvanElburg also updated my code as you suggested but still the same error.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg It looks okay. I could get the json from AuthorityUrl/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't set client.BaseAddress anymore.

Comment: Tried that as well. Then it tried to get values from localhost:5000//.well-known/openid-configuration. :/

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879949/5062791

The summary is, because you're using `TestServer` which is in-memory, `TokenClient` is unable to find any of the endpoint it needs because it's going via internet instead of your in-memory host. You need to tell `TokenClient` to use the `TestServer` handler.

Comment: @ColinM not even close man. I already have the working setup like in the proposed question but problem is replacing obsolete methods which are GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync() and RequestTokenAsync(). Please read the question and the docs. I  have added.

Comment: You said when you didn’t set the client base url you were directed to “localhost:5000//.well-known/openid-configuration”? The request to the document discovery endpoint should never rely on the client’s base url if the address is present on the DiscoveryDocumentRequest (as shown in the source code for the oidc client). What exactly use AuthorityUrl equal to?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve?   I have same issue.